# Toggle styling for active element in group of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Given a group of elements with no target attribute (e.g. following code), what is the most effiecient way to set a highlight-styling for a selected element while unsetting the same styling for a previously selected element ?

```
<div id="uno" class="element_parent">
    <a href="#" class="element">ONE</div>
</div>
<div id="dos" class="element_parent">
    <a href="#" class="element">ONE</div>
</div>
<div id="tres" class="element_parent">
    <a href="#" class="element">ONE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add and remove a class on clicking the anchor, like so:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active')
           .closest('div')
           .siblings('div')
           .find('a')
           .removeClass('active')
});
```

CSS

```
.active {color: red;} /* or whatever */
```

or:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.element.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This answer seems to involve more dom traversal than the others. Is it the most efficient way?

Comment: @bratman - That depends, I don't particularly like just removing classes on all elements with a certain class, but I'd rather make sure the elements I'm targeting is within a certain group of elements etc. I'll add another option that's "shorter", but not neccessarily more efficient, as adding, removing and selecting classes takes more internal parsing in jQuery than just climbing one step up in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $(".element").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.element').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
});
```